# Load full site not mobile version - Javascript window.location

Tags: javascript, redirect, mobile

For a project i am using a redirect to a mobile version if the screen.width is under 768px:

```
if (screen.width < 768) {
window.location = "http://www.site.com/mobile";
}
```

This is fine but now if im on the mobile site i cant get back to the normal site, how can i add a link or change the javascript that if im on the mobile site i can click on a ling "To Full view page" and is not going to the mobile version?

Thanks for your help!
Peesen

Comment: Please don't do this to your users. They _will_ hate you. Instead provide a non-obstrusive link "Hey, we've noticed that you're using a small device, maybe you want to use our mobile page?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a cookie:

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : ";
    expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

and:

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
{
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}
```

adapted from here:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: I found a solution for my problem here:
www.malphursinteractive.com/view-full-site-mobile-redirect-script/